# What does this C++ compilation error mean?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

Does anyone have any clue as to what this might mean?

```
(ClCompile target) -> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

It builds fine on my dev box but fails due to this error on our CI box.  It's running on .NET 3.5.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: looks like cl is crashing (check in eventlog to confirm).  Apply all the altest VS patches/service packs, doesn't help -- reinstall.

Comment: FYI: 0xC0000135 is STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this **[Microsoft Feedback report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/527384/changing-targetframeworkversion-to-v2-0-causes-msb6006-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515)**. From the article:

> The error definitley needs to be a better one. What it should be telling you is that a tool failed. The issue is most likley that you don't have the Visual Studio 2008 bits on your box. So, when the project was re-targeted to the v90 platform toolset (which is the set of Visual Studio 2008 tools; can be installed with the proper version of the Windows SDK that goes with Visual Studio 2008 which I believe is v6.0A) and the tools were not installed, the build failed because it could not find the tools.
>
> The reason that it re-targets to the v90 toolset is because that is the compiler that matches with the version that corresponded to the v2.0 CLR.
>
> Based on where we are in the current cycle, we can't change the message. But, since we need to improve the error message in this scenario, I have resolved as postponed so that we can look at this in the next cycle.

Comment: I have v7 of the windows SDK.  Is there a way that I can force it to use that instead of v6.0A?

Comment: I'm a little confused why the toolset doesn't default to v10 if not specified in the vxproj file.  I'd be less surprised by no-default but I gather the default is for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled across a similar crash:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073740777.

Entirely reproducible and extremely annoying.  In my case it seems to have been related to the insanely long include path list my client uses (over 16Kb of include path text, several hundred include paths to search) and when I cleaned this up and reduced the overall size the crash went away.

My suspicion is therefore that Microsoft have a 16Kb buffer somewhere in their compiler that when full simply bombs.  Hope that helps someone.